# Closing a tensorflow session with RTX GPU

Tags: python, tensorflow

In order to get TF to use my RTX GPU and also use mixed precision training, I'm using TF 2.4 and I have to add these lines to all code that involved training or executing a TF model:

```
if ('RTX' in os.popen('nvidia-smi -L').read()) and ('2.4' in tf.__version__):
    from tensorflow.keras import mixed_precision
    mixed_precision.set_global_policy('mixed_float16')
    from tensorflow.compat.v1 import ConfigProto
    from tensorflow.compat.v1 import InteractiveSession
    config = ConfigProto()
    config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
    session = InteractiveSession(config=config)
```

The if statement is there just because I still have a non-RTX machine and I sometimes use it as well.  The issue is that if I run a script twice with different parameters I always get a warning saying an interactive session is open and this might cause memory leakage.  The easy workaround is to restart Spyder every time, but I'd like to just close the session.  I've tried:

```
tf.InteractiveSession.close()
```

But that throws an error.  I use Keras so I'm not great at pure TF, surely there is a simple command to close the session? THX.

Comment: Try `session.close()`.

Comment: doh, so easy. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to call `.close()` on the **InteractiveSession** class itself, but on an instance of the class.

So, as you have an instance of **InteractiveSession** in the **session** variable, you should use:

`session.close()`.

Comment: If the answer solves your problem or you believe it is the best solution. Please, up-vote and mark this answer as accepted! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

session.close() as posted above by whoisraibolt.